# Which method to solve $2xyy'=x^2+3y^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title states I'm trying to solve $2xyy'=x^2+3y^2$.  I have explored the methods such as integrating factor, separable equations, and exact equations.  The equation above doesn't seem to give way to any of these methods.

Note:  I have never learned the method of exact equations where you multiply by a factor that turns the equation into an exact equation.  That could be it but I wanted to run it by some others to see if maybe I missed something obvious.

Comment: The method you're describing in your note is the method of finding an integrating factor (that you say you've tried), isn't it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is an 'integrating factor' with respect to exact equations.  It may be related to the integrating factor method, but this relation alludes me at the current state of my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

$$2xyy'=x^2+3y^2$$
$$x(y^2)'=x^2+3y^2$$
Substitute $z=y^2$
$$ \implies xz'-3z=x^2$$
$$  x^3z'-3x^2z=x^4$$
$$\left(\frac z {x^3}\right)'=\frac 1 {x^2}$$
Simply integrate

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that the exponents line up correctly, we can rewrite this as

$$2y' = \frac{x}{y} + 3 \frac{y}{x}$$

which suggests the standard substitution $v = y/x$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is homogeneous, so you can use the substitution $u=y/x$, $y'=u'x+u$.